# .NET Are multiple instances of the same form sharing resources?

Tags: .net, forms, winforms, instance, backgroundworker

I'm creating a project where I **instantiate** multiple times the same **Form** which contains some **Timers**, a lot of **Background Workers**, and of course some private arrays, etc.

The problems is that... it doesn't work.

I mean, I can see all the forms, but the `BW`s work only for the first instance, and not for the others, even if `BW.isBusy()` returns `false.
Without returning any errors, they just don't do what they should do.

So, my question is: are some **WinForm** components, like **BW**, shared?

If yes, there is a way to bypass this problem?
If no, what could be the reason of this problem?

Sorry, I can't show you the source and even a screenshot of the software (it's for a client).
But if you need any more details, I will share them.

To instance the forms I'm using something like this:

```
For (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     Form1 f = New Form1();
     f.Show();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably just put a `static` somewhere you shouldn't have.

Comment: Can't find nothing wrong.

Comment: Will you show us how the timers and background workers are initialized/created?

Comment: I created them in the design of the form. But in theory they should be duplicated every time I instance a new Form1 (if I have a button, two Form1s doesn't have the same identical button, in theory, it wouldn't have any sense). I will try later to instance them in runtime.

Comment: Form should not share any private resources/controls. `new Form1()` will always create new instance. They can be shared only if you declare controls with `static/Shared` keyword. If controls are not static, then your problem in initialization of multiple instances. Some initialization logic wasn't executed correctly. For finding real problem - show/tell what `BackgroundWorker` do and how you check it is not working. If you shared some state between `BackgroundWorkers` then it possible that after first instance start other workers starts and immediately completes

Answer (score 0):

I found a "**workaround**" for my problem.
Instead of instancing **N** times the **Form**, I start **N** separate processes with arguments I need.

```
For (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  ProcessStartInfo pHelp = new ProcessStartInfo();
  pHelp.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\mySoft.exe";
  pHelp.Arguments = arg1 + "," + arg2 + "," + arg3;
  pHelp.UseShellExecute = true;
  pHelp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
  Process proc = Process.Start(pHelp);
}
```

And then in the **Form_Load()**

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
// 
// Here code to split the args, which starts at index 1 of the array.
//
Form1 f = New Form1();
// 
// Here code to change some form variables.
// ex. f.Var1 = arg1;
//
f.Show();
Me.Close();
```

It's not the best solution, but the problem vanishes and in my case it's ok to have multiple processes instead of multiple forms.